# Reading simple API returns blank screen?

Tags: php, http-headers

For some reason I cannot figure out how to fix this online anywhere?  I have this simple free Chuck Norris joke API that I'm simply trying to output the JSON of, but it wont work?  I just get a blank screen?

In the console the network tab says 200 ok and that the headers are valid? What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
<?php

  
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('X-RapidAPI-Host: matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com');
  header('X-RapidAPI-Key: 341b5c1156msh6827bf7184ef4ddp1c8d09jsnbc52db5d01be');
 


  $str = file_get_contents('https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/random');
  
// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// get the data

print_r($json);
```

Comment: Note: works fine in postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you want to send those headers...

`header` prints out the headers to you, locally, where you execute it.

With `file_get_contents` it will be like this:

```php
<?php
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com\r\n" .
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: 341b5c1156msh6827bf7184ef4ddp1c8d09jsnbc52db5d01be\r\n"
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$str = file_get_contents('https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/random', false, $context);

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// get the data
print_r($json);
```

I also kindly suggest switching to `curl` extension.

Comment: Great this works,  when they allow me to get the answer I'll give it to you.  Questions: why won't calling regular headers like I do work?  and curl I just need to install from terminal and will work on my local files?

Comment: Maybe because I did not have the method?

Comment: Essentially you are setting response headers. You need to send request headers.

Comment: The connection flow is as follows: `[You] <-> [Your script] <-> [API]`. `header` function sends data between `[You] and [Your script]` while those headers include auth keys for accessing the `[API]` so need to be sent between `[Your script] and [API]`. And that happens in my example above. `curl` is meant for handling external urls sending/downloading. `file_get_contents` was intended mostly for accessing files and it relies on few settings in the php.ini active for even working with external urls.